# After backing up a database, I can't restore the selected database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm having trouble retrieving the .db file from DB card.

I used this code for backup database:

```
private void DBBackup() {

    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();


        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = getContext().getDatabasePath(DBHelper.DB_NAME).getPath();
            String backupDBPath = "DBBackupTest";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Export Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

after several minutes, I want to import the backed up database. This is the code for Import

```
  try {
                File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
                if (sd.canWrite()) {
                    String currentDBPath = "/storage/emulated/legacy/DBBackup";
                    String backupDBPath = "DBBackupTest"; // From SD directory.
                    File backupDB = new File(currentDBPath);
                    File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);


                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Import Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

The `Toast` show "Import Successful!" but when i check the database by using `stetho`. the database isn't attached. I need your help on this. thanks!

Comment: Have you tried stopping and the starting the device after the restore? So that all caches are cleared, which I believe is the likely issue. i.e. The restore is fine but it's just not seen.

Comment: You may find [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317525/how-to-restore-sqlite-database-after-backup-android/44318566#44318566) useful

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing my `currentDB` and change it from:

```
 File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
```

to:

```
 File currentDB = new File(getContext().getDatabasePath(DBHelper.DB_NAME).getPath());
```