# Reading data from a backup text file after restoring room database

Tags: java, android, string, split, android-room

I am building an app that backs up and restores a room database in Android Studio. The backup process works fine however when I try to restore the database (Using a Recyclerview) it won't show me all the data. I suspect the issue could be reading the Strings from the text file.

Here's my method

```
  public void restoreDatabase() throws IOException {
        File backupFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), AppDatabase.DATABASE_NAME + ".txt");

        if (!backupFile.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Backup file does not exist");
        }

        AppDatabase database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "InnBucks_DB").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        UserDao userDao = database.userDao();

        try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(backupFile)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                String line = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // Split the line into user data
                String[] userData = line.split(" ");

                // Create a new user object
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(Integer.parseInt(userData[0]));
                user.setUserId(userData[1]);
                user.setName(userData[2]);

                // Add the user to the database
                userDao.registerUser(user);
            }
        }

// Get the list of users from the database.
        List<User> userList = userDao.getallusers();

// Call the setUserList() method on the RecyclerView adapter to update the list of users.
        userListAdapter.setUserList(userList);

// Notify the RecyclerView adapter that the data has changed.
        userListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Database restored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is my database before I click delete and then restore
[image]

And when I restore the database, this the output and as you can see there is data missing
[image]

Comment: does stopping and restarting the App, then display the correct data? Due to the underlying complexity of the behind the scenes SQLiteOpenHelper you may well have to  somehow clear all the underlying instances and perhaps restarting the activity is the solution  as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317525/how-to-restore-sqlite-database-after-backup-android/44318566#44318566 (as an example).