# Replay backup database in Android

Tags: android-sqlite

I do not know how to do it although I already looked for a solution on the Internet. I want to replay my backup database in Android.

Currently, I am creating a backup of my database like that:

```
    final File[] databases = new File(context.getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/databases").listFiles();
    for (File databaseFile: databases) {
        File backupFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), databaseFile.getName() + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".db");
        FileChannel inputChannel = null;
        FileChannel outputChannel = null;

        if(databaseFile.getName().startsWith("DATABASE")) {
            try {
                inputChannel = new FileInputStream(databaseFile.getAbsolutePath()).getChannel();
                outputChannel = new FileOutputStream(backupFile).getChannel();
                outputChannel.transferFrom(inputChannel, 0, inputChannel.size());
...
```

Now I would like to replay my backup since I have changed my mobile phone and I need my data on the new phone.

If somebody know a way how I can do that?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically reverse the process.

1. Ascertain the location of the backup file (perhaps using a file picker).
2. Delete the existing file(s) if one from it's location typically in the databases folder/directory which can be ascertained by using a Context's [getDatabasePath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) method

   1. note that files that are the same name as the database file name but prefixed with -wal, -shm or -journal should also be deleted.
3. Copy the file(s) (-wal and - shm if they existed and were backed up) from their backup location to the location they should be.

- note that you could overwrite the files rather than delete, alternately you  could rename it/them which would then leave a copy of the pre restored database.
- note that you may well wish to restart the App after the restore, this being the simplest way to handle to cleanup of all the activities which may be accessing the old database.

More at [How to restore Sqlite database after backup Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317525/how-to-restore-sqlite-database-after-backup-android/44318566#44318566)

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

I just have one last question. I always get FileNotFoundException although the DB backup file is located here: Downloads folder Google Pixel 7 mobile phone and I pick it.

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityResultLauncher = ...
     public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
         Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
         File source = new File(uri.getPath());
         File destination = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath()+"/databases/DATABASE_RUN.db");
copy(source, destination);

Comment: This is the logcat:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/msf:1000007219: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @Bernd you may have to do a `mkdirs` to create the databases folder if it doesn't exist. Also files names are case sensitive.

Comment: The database folder exists since there is an existing db file in it.
What does not work is when I pick the backup file and then I want to copy it to the destination folder it does not work because the picked file does not exist anymore.
What I know is that this /document/msf:.... path is not a real path but this is the only URI that I get.

Comment: I put my backup file to some other places. I am still able to pick it from there but as soon as it should be copied to the destination folder I always get the FileNotFoundException as if the source file does not exist.

I put the file here now: sqlite-db folder on local storage, and the debugger says: /root/storage/emulated/0/sqlite-db/DATABASE_RUN.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I solved it the following way now:

InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(result.getData().getData());
Uri uris = Uri.fromFile(new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getParentFile().getPath() + "/databases/DATABASE_RUN"));
OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uris);
copy(is, out);
}
copy part:
        final byte[] b = new byte[8192];
        for (int r; (r = in.read(b)) != -1;) {
            out.write(b, 0, r);
        }

Thank you very much for your help!